# Como ajustar um grid em HTML

Tags: html, css, imagem, grid

Oi! Estou com problemas para montar um grid com duas imagens + texto em HTML (é para um post de blog, então preciso que seja HTML mesmo).

Preciso que a imagem da estrada fique a esquerda, com a foto da frase a direita, alinhada por cima (com uma margem de distancia de 10px) e o texto abaixo (com a mesma margem).

Mas não consigo, quando monto o HTML ele fica alinhando tudo pelo centro e não consigo colocar o texto para baixo da segunda imagem.

O HTML que usei:

```
<table> 
    <tr> 
        <td align="right" widht="50%"><IMG SRC="https://static.tumblr.com/5effaa89329ee96ba67275cc51bb0be2/z1lgkb5/Lu8nwwpgi/tumblr_static_filename_640_v2.jpg" alt=“essa foto precisa ficar alinhada a esquerda“></td> 
       <td align=“left” widht="50%"><IMG SRC="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ac/7c/b8/ac7cb8dc771754f451a2c404222cea0f--love-quotes-net.jpg" alt=“esse precisa ficar acima do texto“ width:"150px"></td> <BR>
       <td widht="50%"> <mark style="background-color:black; color:white;">Work— </mark> preciso que este texto fique ao lado da imagem da estrada, com a imagem da frase acima dele. </td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Para ficar claro, você quer duas colunas? A coluna na esquerda com a foto e a coluna a direita com uma foto em cima de texto?

Comment: @GetulioRafaelFerreira agora que vc já esclareceu, apaguei os comentários anteriores só para dar uma organizada e jajá apago este aqui. Obrigado pelo retorno!

Comment: Posso estar dizendo besteira, mas pelo que entendi se você usar grid no Css deve funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi minha sugestão envolve apenas HTML e CSS.

HTML:

```
    <p class="paragrafo">
    <img class="minha-image"  src="" width="100" height="100"/>
    Nunc pulvinar lacus id purus ultrices id sagittis neque 
convallis. Nunc vel libero orci. Vivamus at dolor a nibh aliquet luctus. 
Duis imperdiet mi id lorem pellentesque tempus. Ut nterdum 
molestie ornare tellus consectetur.
    </p>
```

CSS:

```
.minha-image{
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
}
.paragrafo{
  clear: left;
}
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro o uso do bootstrap assim ja ficara responsivo:

```
<img alt="" src="" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<img alt="" src="" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
<p class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">texto</p>
```

Nesse exeplo todos estão ocupando o mesmo espaço, 50% da tela cada, se as imagens tiverem uma altura muito grande pode não ficar perfeito. Você também pode arrumar do jeito que achar melhor

Leia mais sobre isso [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)